# Headers issue (Angular): server responds with 401 and 200 in the same request?

Tags: angular, http, header, authorization

I have this small app asking a service to an API. I have set the credentials like this:

```
this.http.get<Response>(url, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Basic ' 
        + btoa('C7YHKF91RAABYXNK :JMGYBMAT1X18KA2W '))
      })
        .subscribe(data => {
          Response = data['results'];
```

But the logs are "strange":
[image]

There's a 401 and then a 200 and the API is not returning what was suposed to return (a png image). On Edge, when I hit submit, the browser asks for the token. I input the credentials and then the service works (chrome is similar)...Yesterday everything was working fine, but now I have this problem. Is it the API? Are the headers wrongly set up? I have a live demo for testing [here](https://space-junior.000webhostapp.com/). Thanks for the help!

EDIT as suggested by @Mudassar

```
onSubmit({ valid }: { valid: boolean }, f: any) {

    if {//
    } 
    else {

      let color = encodeURIComponent(this.params.handwriting_color);
      const url =
        `https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?handwriting_id=${this.params.handwriting_id}&text=${this.params.text}&handwriting_size=${this.params.handwriting_size}&handwriting_color=${color}`;

      //SET HEADERS
      let headers= new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('C7YHKF91RAABYXNK :JMGYBMAT1X18KA2W '))
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "new[] { (string)context.Request.Headers['Origin'] }");
      headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "new[] { 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' }");
      headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "new[] { 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' }");
      headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "new[] { 'true' }");




      //REQUEST
      this.http.get<Response>(url, {
        headers: headers
      })
        .subscribe(data => {
          Response = data['results'];

        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          } else {
            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
            console.log(Response);
          }
        });
    }
```

But I still get the 401...

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to not setting the CORS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

further setting this should ensure proper working

```
 headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { (string)context.Request.Headers["Origin"] });
 headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" });
 headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" });
 headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] { "true" });
```

EDIT: Starting to feel the problem might be to do with the server side hence suggesting to add on the server side to expose the Authorization header.
 `"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" : "Authorization"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mudassar; I've searched similar issues trying to correctly implement the the Access Control, but I still can't do it right. Yo mean that I need to set that along the token?

Comment: I've tried like this:  `this.http.get<Response>(url, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set(Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Basic 
        + btoa(C7YHKF91RAABYXNK :JMGYBMAT1X18KA2W ))
      }) ` but I get the 401

Comment: Thanks @Mudassar, I was already getting into the subject and your solution seems very complete, bullet proof :)

Comment: Sorry @Mudassar, i'm still getting the same response. The way you typed I got underlined because headers only accept 2 arguments. But then I've done it in other way, see my edit